# Insert multiple lines of one attribute in yaml file with yq v4.x

Tags: yaml, yq

There is a dynamic attribute stored in input.yaml, I want to insert it into an existed yaml file(named as original.yaml). The attribute has multiple lines.

The two files look like:
input.yaml:

```
- name: bob
  spec: {}
```

original.yaml:

```
spec:
    names:
      - name: alice
        spec: {}
```

My goal is to put input.yaml content under original.yaml `spec.names`.
I tried with yq version 4:

```
env=$(cat input.yaml)
yq eval '.spec.names + strenv(env)' original.yaml > result.yaml
```

What I got：

```
spec:
  names:
    - name: alice
      spec: {}
    - |-
      - name: bob
        spec: {}
```

there is an unwanted `- |-` in line 5, I am expected the below output:

```
spec:
  names:
    - name: alice
      spec: {}
    - name: bob
      spec: {}
```

Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea is right, but you shouldn't be using `strenv()` function, which formats your input as a YAML string type. Your `names` record is a an array of maps, so you need to retain the original type, by just using `env`

So, with that and avoiding `cat` and using the shell input redirection (should work on bash/zsh/ksh), you could do

```sh
item="$(< input.yaml)" yq e '.spec.names += env(item)' original.yaml
```